# Jordan's decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I have a matrix $A\in R^{n,n}$.

$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-2&0&0&\dots&0\\
0&1&0&-6&0&\dots&0\\
0&0&1&0&-12&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&-(n-2)(n-1)\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$

$A$ is a matrix with $1$ on diagonal and two spots to the right is $-i(i+1)$, where $i$ is the line number.

It has a characteristic polynomial $p_A(t)=(1-t)^n$.

So jordan's form of this matrix has $1$ on diagonal, and $0$ or $1$ above it.

EDIT:

$J=
\begin{bmatrix}
J_1 & 0 & 0 &\dots& 0\\
0&J_2&0&\dots&0\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \dots &0\\
0&0&0&\dots&J_n
\end{bmatrix}$

Where 
$J_i=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0&0 & \dots & 0\\
0 &1 &1&0&\dots&0\\
0&0&1&1&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\dots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$

How do I know how many blocks $J_i$(and of what size) are used in $J$ matrix?

Comment: After the edit, it still depends on $A$. Are you looking for a general description, is that it?

Comment: yes of course we need the matrix...

Comment: Added the base matrix.

Comment: There is an explicit formula for the number of blocks of size $k$ in terms of the dimension of the kernel of $(A-\lambda I)$ raised to certain powers. It is on the wikipedia page for JNF.

Comment: I can't understand what $A$ is. After $-12$ is everything $0$?

Comment: Each row of $A$ looks like this: $1$ on diagonal, then first element to the right is $0$, and the next to the right from that $0$ is $-i(i+1)$, where $i$ is the number of row. In other spots is it $0$.

Comment: @Josh Then you don't get an all $0$'s last column.

Comment: Oh, that's true. Fixed.

Comment: I edited my answer. Is it now clear to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: you cannot with minimal polynomial, which would tell you what is the biggest block. However without further details, you cannot go any further.

also note that Jordan's matrix is not unique, so i don't quite know what 'is it 0 or 1' above each entry means.

Edit:

let me give you an example, take n = 5,

I can only tell you the possible block size combinations are

$(1,1,1,1,1)$, $(2,1,1,1)$, $(2,2,1)$, $(3,1,1)$, $(3,2)$, $(4,1)$, $(5)$

(the first one mean 5 blocks of size 1, etc)

without knowing the minimal polynomial. Basically, it is the possible combinations are ways you can break up $n$ into sum of integers.

EDIT: for your given matrix, there are 2 jordan blocks

$J_(n-1)$ and $J_1$

To show this:

show $A^k \neq 0$ for $k < n$, so $q(t) = (1-t)^{n-1}$ is the minimal polynomial, the biggest block is size $n-1$

The only possible Jordan block decomposition is $J_{n-1}$ and $J_1$, so there are $(n-2)$ 1's and one 0 above the diagonal.

Comment: My interpretation of Josh's question is that he would like to know how to determine the Jordan blocks of $A$ when written in JCF.

Comment: @Dan So is mine and this answers addresses that. It's not possible to know.

Comment: @GitGud: Oh yes absolutely. I didn't mean to suggest Lost1's answer is incomplete. I just meant to provide a possible interpretation of Josh's question. Glad to know someone else read it that way! `:)`

Comment: I eddited the question to be more precise.
If you need the original matrix $A$ to help me I can provide it aswell.